# Using Intersection Observer to target the same class at different times throughout the page

Tags: numbers, counter, intersection-observer

I've got various animated counters throughout a page which need to count up to the specified number when they each become visible for the first time within the browser viewport.

The following code works but activates all of the counters at the same time (even when not visible).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            function startCounter(){
                $('.counter').each(function() {
                    var num = jQuery(this), countTo = num.attr("data-count");
                    var decimal = 0;
                    if (countTo.indexOf(".") > 0) { 
                        decimal = countTo.toString().split(".")[1].length; 
                    }
                    $({ countNum: num.text()}).animate({ countNum: countTo }, {
                        duration: 3000, easing:"swing", step: function() {
                            num.text(parseFloat(this.countNum).toFixed(decimal));
                            //num.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                        }, complete: function() {
                            num.text(this.countNum);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }   

            let counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
            
            let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
              (entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    startCounter();
                    //observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                  }
                });
              },
              { threshold: 1 }
            );

            counters.forEach(counter => {
              observer.observe(counter);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

```
    <body>
        <div class="counter" data-count="1000.45"></div><div class="counter" data-count="2306.33"></div>
        <div style="height:100vh;"></div>
        <div class="counter" data-count="98"></div>
        <div class="counter" data-count="560"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting all the elements with the class 'counter' in startCounter function by using `$('.counter').each(function()`.

So for each entry in your observer, i.e if any of the entries become visible on DOM, all the elements (i.e counters) get affected.

You only have to target the entry which is visible (i.e isIntersecting) on DOM, so it is suggested that you pass that particular element(entry.target) as an argument to startCounter, and only make the necessary changes on that particular element

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Say1218 who pointed me in the right direction, below now works perfectly.

The thing I was missing was I needed to target only the specific `entry.target` when it came into view.

So I told `new IntersectionObserver` to add a class of `.countup` when each `entry.target` became visible e.g.

`entry.target.classList.add('countup');`

```
            let images = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
            
            let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
              (entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    // add a class of .countup to the current entry-target
                    entry.target.classList.add('countup');
                    countUp();
                    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                    console.log(entry.target);
                  }
                });
              },
              { threshold: 1 }
            );

            images.forEach(image => {
              observer.observe(image);
            });
```

Then in the `countUp()` function, I told it to apply for all divs with the class `.countup.counter`

```
            function countUp() {
                $('.countup.counter').each(function() {
                    var num = jQuery(this), countTo = num.attr("data-count");
                    var decimal = 0;
                    if (countTo.indexOf(".") > 0) { 
                        decimal = countTo.toString().split(".")[1].length; 
                    }
                    $({ countNum: num.text()}).animate({ countNum: countTo }, {
                        duration: 3000, easing:"swing", step: function() {
                            num.text(parseFloat(this.countNum).toFixed(decimal));
                        }, complete: function() {
                            num.text(this.countNum);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

But because the initial HTML remained as before, the `countUp()` function was only triggered once `IntersectionObserver` had added the class of `.countup`

```
        <div class="counter" data-count="1000.45" data-speed="20"></div>
        <div class="counter" data-count="96.25" data-speed="20"></div>
        <div class="counter" data-count="34" data-speed="20"></div>
        <div style="height:100vh;"></div>
        <div class="counter" data-count="10000" data-speed="20"></div>
```

Ingenious lol! That was a head scratcher for a while